# `if constexpr` in fold expression

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, if-constexpr, fold-expression

I am trying to make a fold expression in a function which populates the outgoing parameters of a function with some values that come in from a string vector. My fold expression is like:

```cpp
  ((if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<Args>)
  {
      args = std::stoi(vec[index++]);
  }
  else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Args, std::string>)
  {
      args = vec[index++];
  }
  else
  {
      throw std::invalid_argument("Unsupported argument type.");
  }), ...);
```

but it fails to compile with a strange error message:

```
clang: error: expected expression
```

or

```
gcc: error: expected primary-expression before 'if'
```

(as seen on https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xeq3j6oE7)

Does anyone have a hint on how to properly fix this?

**Edit**

Full context for the problem is this short application:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
template <typename... Args>
void populateArgs(std::vector<std::string>& vec, Args&... args)
{
    const size_t numArgs = sizeof...(Args);
    if (vec.size() != numArgs)
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Number of arguments doesn't match the size of the vector.");
    }
    int index = 0;
    ((if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<Args>)
      {
          args = std::stoi(vec[index++]);
      }
      else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Args, std::string>)
      {
          args = vec[index++];
      }
      else
      {
          throw std::invalid_argument("Unsupported argument type.");
      }), ...);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> vec{ "1", "2", "3", "hello" };
    short a;
    int b;
    long long c;
    std::string d;
    populateArgs(vec, a, b, c, d);
    std::cout << "a = " << a << ", b = " << b << ", c = " << c << ", d = " << d << std::endl;
    // Output: a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = hello
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

```
([&]{
    // if constexpr ...
}(), ...);
```

This creates a lambda and immediately calls it.

---

I remember this causing some problems on MSVC. If it doesn't work for you, you can try:

```
([&]<typename T>()
{
    // Use `T` instead of `Args` here.
}.operator()<Args>(), ...);
```

, or a separate template function.

Comment: like this https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/o3feWz1aG

Comment: @HolyBlackCat would you mind adding some explanation why the obscurity with the lambda is required? Thanks!

Comment: @FerencDeak expressions have a value. `if ...` is a statement https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if

Comment: That's fair enough, thank you! :D

Comment: @FerencDeak There's not much to it. A function body can only contain a sequence of statements (e.g. `if constexpr (...) {...}` is a statement). `expression;` is also a kind statement. But a fold expression expects an expression as the operand, and `if constexpr` isn't one.

Answer (score 1):

`if constexpr` imho is not a great way of doing a "switch" on types. Imho you're better off creating overloads of a function template instead.

Furthermore I strongly recommend causing a compiler error to indicate invalid parameters being passed to `populateArgs`.

```
// set to 0 to use exception instead
#define DETECT_ERROR_AT_COMPILETIME 1

// set to 1 to simulate an invalid use of populateArgs 
#define USE_INCORRECT_CALL 0

namespace impl // use a suitable namespace in case the functionality becomes part of a header file
{
template<class T>
constexpr bool AlwaysFalse = false;

template<class T>
void AssignFromConvertedString(T& lhs, std::string const& str)
{
#if DETECT_ERROR_AT_COMPILETIME
    static_assert(AlwaysFalse<T>, "Unsupported argument type.");
#else
    throw std::invalid_argument("Unsupported argument type.");
#endif
}

template<std::integral T>
void AssignFromConvertedString(T& lhs, std::string const& value)
{
    lhs = std::stoi(value);
}

inline void AssignFromConvertedString(std::string& lhs, std::string const& value)
{
    lhs = value;
}

}

template <typename... Args>
void populateArgs(std::vector<std::string>& vec, Args&... args)
{
    const size_t numArgs = sizeof...(Args);
    if (vec.size() != numArgs)
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Number of arguments doesn't match the size of the vector.");
    }
    size_t index = 0;
    ((impl::AssignFromConvertedString(args, vec[index++])), ...);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> vec{ "1", "2", "3", "hello" };
    short a;
    int b;
#if USE_INCORRECT_CALL
    std::nullptr_t c;
#else
    long long c;
#endif
    std::string d;
    populateArgs(vec, a, b, c, d);
    std::cout << "a = " << a << ", b = " << b << ", c = " << c << ", d = " << d << std::endl;
    // Output: a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = hello
}
```

[Code on godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEIABsABykAA6oCoRODB7evnppGY4CIWGRLDFxyXaYDllCBEzEBDk%2BfgHVtQL1jQQlEdGxCVUNTS15XLYjvaH95YOJAJS2qF7EyOwc5gDMocjeWADUJltuAG41RMTH2CYaAILbu/uYRycKBMShwNe3D2Y7DD2XkOxzcBAAnilMAB9D5MQgKH73R6A56vNxOd7ETCsJF/AFAkFvAhYVTrFIEPEowkvUFoQGYCmIrY3ZH3AD07IOSgIByIBw0fNQBy8SgOmDJjKKDAOoXeOPQv22WBoYQOABFsAAVbBuLXQ7AAJUNAHlDdC7vq3CaALLKACSQW19pt2AOXCVHK5PKF7t9GRYXgMBBehllDFOYjw6BFYtQVAOaRSQaYIbuxGACiOyP%2BKpmBzkQmw0Pt4Wtxt1VruQSCAs9d2YbAUKSY61lLBStAOnNjoe5XkITCi9AOjcwzdbL1CB1EYoICBeVC8gOlUYhBxiaCbiZ6B3jByYBwXTCwxAONHoSoA7FZ7iGO8HMHSDAos1q8fT5aoUmeoqhPAcdy0AA7kw4IKAAYmIYrHOq57QU%2BWy3g8d6YA%2BqaIW4exMK%2BBzviyvynKg0aAa%2BeDAAwEHEKgLAeBGsQhug9SfEYEDvmY8QHLQCAKKQ3IkiAIBYl8M4CO85icViCzXshjwJpqOp6gaxpmhaVq2g6Tpai6rJ3Ac%2Bn8ameDINCOFKE0EBAaB4FQbQSigvh2B8eYZhyAwCheCkaRNJgMaNMAPiMLyEJQgAdC50lIUq/yYHZT73AZfIINRwH8eggmhJGtDRqZGaBYIEAuW5HleSQjEHnlbCCHykKYOFZhmJFskxQw%2BBUNe6r1venYYaC7zpSAoQhsAxBiHheJESRdxkRRVE0XR5w%2BUxHxfGxElcTxfH9YJwlGKJ7mUhxBxZV4mDSciN6/Il3FZrBaU7UQeAQCdZ3HLJV6dWydyhNlaqTTG00ZLN1G0QIi2Mcxq3bUJK1GOtN1bQJMMscA%2B3iUdL3nQ8l0JQZN2vHBL1vR19YmB9XVoT1IboiFjCsHVoWhYBGbMrp/2JqgyaPummYQND5wOCQfVI7t3wERjNR8TziIcYzTP%2BQoWNk8hiWfryGQAF4wryDA%2BNLBPcngWvxnLlks01V0GXgCbPTUoWa5gEALAcYBgHdussNLWOJcrluJfp84pfdg0RlG6C5QFVUEIVDVlBUe4Jv5%2BUEFm6CoOODBgBwvIsKmyAIElLwOwnhfHRcJD1Y1xO4/pZOfXpBkO7C4akgbGjVw3%2BlQHgD6CYD5GUSDC0Mb5kOsQrfECyYACsFihKS1iL9P6oLEsBxyxbF3178Q0HLnoROzJfvBwLlzCwNovXGXpg3kcDUeg1zkNWYLlP/8r932YC60LQqAuUc5Moo125AgMqB4O6JV3lEDuckCxFhLGWM0hpKzQjcNWIIx9oa6x/hSYgzdTBAPxLFeywDf57TIajAhzUtiuGtpgkWsNUaKkIYlJMKY0ws1tsgPiTA%2BJRD4twg46BN6d2DmgLwvJQSgk/oeO6/8pEnAPOiaRH8ogG3kScaRaiFFuE/gI9RDVlGKOQEY3RH8YxyMMTooRpjg6uFoBAgyPYTQSOTAQEASi7oTA3AbAIM4DZbD4hYrYcFv6/w6hwJYtBODT14H4DgWhSCoE4G4RelhuQrDWLSf4PBSDuISZEpYABrEAkgACcoUrwaHKVwRIGgthmCvIkJIZT9CcEkHEzQvBkkcF4AoEAGg8ldKWHAWAMBEAoBoikOgsRyCUC3NM%2BgcRsJGC4PEDQgysCnGMpgAAangTAwETRQnibki8IZiD9IgFELppAoihEaOCTguT7nMGIOCE0URtAXGebwLcUcTQMFoE8gppAsC5yMOIUF%2BBsS1HOP00FEoagSI2IkoasVbnZSiKNd5HgsC/LyZ8FgvylhUAMJmfZhzjmMAJfwQQIgxDsCkDIQQigVDqFBboCYBgjAoDSTYLF/TIBLE5tKBFABafqsFTCWGsGYRJHRpQuFamMPwExggzDjoMCYBRMgCFVfkdIeqGB9C1XECYiq6hTANRa2KFwrU9FNQMc1kweg2tdU0J1cxzVLAUJk9YEgokxM6aCnpBxVDNPFfESQM4eWozWaFDQiaDgQFwIQEgd8thcAWLwfJWhV6kBKdPQZ0SOAdNIMS4toVp6SCaVeaeXAOJbCvLUgI8TEk9L6QMoZBSRnjIgEgFYBA3FzIgL5dNnx0oTDpcIUQ4hmUzrZWoW5XLSDAVGikElbSOCxNIO27pnAXHDokSXCN8Qo0xpWfG%2BIibk0QA8B2GZZ5tjZtzcMpYx5TyUCDWW3gxLymhUkNPMwjbJCJCvFseIZhEi1L3bcztthu15sKYWkAVazBlOLTBsp8QrwgazVwae26tgho7ZwN9vaf1mFIwe3pPb81LEWhkZwkggA%3D%3D%3D)